# How get text inside element TD DomXPath

Tags: php, domxpath

At page there are elements TEXT

I tried make such:

```
$tables = $xpath->query("//td[@class='enterHeader']");

            foreach($tables as $a){
               print $a->nodeValue." - ".$a->getAttribute("text")."<br/>";
            }
```

But it did give me result...
What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//td[@class='enterHeader']/text()[normalize-space()]`

should get you all text nodes from the cell

---

You can cast the results to a string:

```
print $xpath->evaluate(
           "string(//td[@class='enterHeader']/text()[normalize-space()])");
```

Or if you want to get a DOMNodeList and iterate it:

```
$tNodes = $xpath->query("//td[@class='enterHeader']/text()[normalize-space()]");

foreach($tNodes as $tNode
  print $tNode->textContent;
```

Comment: $tables = $xpath->query("//td[@class='enterHeader']/text()[normalize-space()]");

            foreach($tables as $a){
      print $a->nodeValue;
   }

Comment: You don't need to work on the NodeList if you just need the text content. See my edit

Comment: print $xpath->evaluate  gives me empty result, page is clean

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath should be:

```
//td[@class='enterHeader']/text()
```